# Block Webpage Error window when Disable JavaScript debugging is unchecked in IE11

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, frontend, internet-explorer-11

When I want to add a breakpoint on a click event for a script that has errored out in IE11, I have to uncheck **Disable JavaScript Debugging [ ]** in Internet Options > Advanced > Settings in order to do so. However, a Webpage Error window will then pop up when I reload the page and it will not let me proceed unless I click on the **Do not show this message again [ ]** checkbox (as seen below). However, when I click that, it automatically checks the Disable JavaScript Debugging option again, so I am stuck in a loop where I'm unable to proceed to the page and step through the code. When I try to X out of the window, the window will appear again and again to flag other errors it's found, preventing me from adding the breakpoint.

Is there a way around this?

[image: Webpage Error in IE]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the F12 developer tools to debug JavaScript in IE11? You can directly add breakpoint in [Debugger tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v=vs.85)) without unchecking **Disable JavaScript Debugging**. And if you open the F12 developer tools, the webpage error will not show.